# How to convert pandas dataframe rows into columns, based on category?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a category variable and some number variables. Something like this:

```
ls = [{'count':5, 'module':'payroll', 'id':2}, {'count': 53, 'module': 'general','id':2}, {'id': 5,'count': 35, 'module': 'tax'}, ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ls)
```

The df looks like this:

```
 df
Out[15]: 
   count  id   module
0      5   2  payroll
1     53   2  general
2     35   5      tax
```

I want convert(transpose is the right word?) the module variables into columns and group by the id. So something like:

```
   general_count  id  payroll_count  tax_count
0           53.0   2            5.0        NaN
1            NaN   5            NaN       35.0
```

One approach to this would be to use apply:

```
df['payroll_count'] = df.id.apply(lambda x: df[df.id==x][df.module=='payroll'])
```

However, this suffers from multiple drawbacks:

1. Costly, and takes too much time
2. Creates artifacts and empty
       dataframes that need to be cleaned up.

I sense there's a better way to achieve this with [pandas groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), but can't find a way to this same operation more efficiently. Please help.

Comment: In your desired output, `id` in the first row should be 2, right?

Comment: Yep. fixed it.. Thanks for pointing out.. @jezrael has given a nice answer too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns which first create new `index` and last `column`. then need aggreagate some way - I use [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html), then convert one column `DataFrame` to `Series` by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) (then is not necessary remove top level of Multiindex in columns) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html). Last [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to column name:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','module']).mean().squeeze().unstack().add_suffix('_count')
print (df)
module  general_count  payroll_count  tax_count
id                                             
2                53.0            5.0        NaN
5                 NaN            NaN       35.0
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then need remove `Multiindex` from columns by `list comprehension`:

```
df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='module')
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[1], col[0])) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
    general_count  payroll_count  tax_count
id                                         
2            53.0            5.0        NaN
5             NaN            NaN       35.0
```

Comment: Thanks.. The groupby is solution fits my case perfectly. The pivot may cause problems as I'm trying to cluster the data.  A bit of explanation on how that groupby  will be useful for others.

Comment: Ok, give me as ec

Answer (score 2):

You could use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [2]: df.set_index(['id','module'])['count'].unstack().add_suffix('_count').reset_index()
Out[2]:
module  id  general_count  payroll_count  tax_count
0        2           53.0            5.0        NaN
1        5            NaN            NaN       35.0
```